# I try to get the shortest way between nodes, count certain nodes on the way and return the targets along with the start

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a problem in with cypher and could not solve it by myself. What I want seems to be very complex:

I have specified a node by ID. Then I want the shortest route to other nodes of the same type, but under certain conditions. Then I want to count certain nodes on the way. Finally, I want to return the starting node along with the goals.

My query so far looks like this:

```
MATCH path=(location:Location)-[:CanTravel*1..4]-(property:Gate)<-[:CanTravel]-(destination:Location) 
WHERE property.size IN ['medium', 'large'] AND location.name = 'Ellis' 
RETURN nodes(path)
```

The actual result looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3Ueb.png)

The result have to look like this:

```
locations: [ 
   {
       name: abc,
       travels: 0
   },
   {   name: def,
       travels: 1
   },
   and so far
]
```

Hope anyone can help me :/

Regards, Cavez

EDIT:

result:

```
MATCH path=(location:Solarsystem)-[:CanTravel*1..6]-(property:JumpPoint)<-[:CanTravel]-(destination:Solarsystem) 
WHERE property.size IN ['large'] AND location.name = 'Ellis' 
WITH location, destination, min(size([node in nodes(path) where 
node:JumpPoint])) as travels
WITH location, collect({name:destination, travels:travels}) as locations, 
Collect(destination) + location as nodes
WITH locations + {name:location, travels:0} as locations, nodes
UNWIND nodes as n
RETURN n, locations
```

EDIT 2:

I still have one more thing: I find it confusing that the following result comes out with this query. Again a look at the picture I attached:

```
MATCH path=(location:Solarsystem)-[:CanTravel*1..6]-(jumpPoint:JumpPoint)<-[:CanTravel]-(destination:Solarsystem)
WHERE jumpPoint.size IN ['small'] AND location.name = 'Ellis' 
RETURN path
```

https://www.instpic.de/g2yycmgQZOGKmEsIOEeI.PNG

My expected result is: No results, because I have only filtered a path with small sizes and the start 'Ellis' is not connected with any Gate with the size of small...

Comment: What is `travels` in your expected results? What nodes are you counting?

Comment: travels is the count of the ":Gate" nodes on each path. Thanks for your reply! 

It could be help, to extract all nodes of the path separately by :Location and :Gate, or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the number of :Gate nodes in the path with a simple filtering of path nodes:

```
MATCH path=(location:Location)-[:CanTravel*1..4]-(property:Gate)<-[:CanTravel]-(destination:Location) 
WHERE property.size IN ['medium', 'large'] AND location.name = 'Ellis' 
RETURN location.name as start, collect({name:destination.name, travels:size([node in nodes(path) where node:Gate])}) as locations
```

EDIT

Okay, so let's make sure we have only the shortest path to each destination, and then add in the current location to the collection too, with travels:0

```
MATCH path=(location:Location)-[:CanTravel*1..4]-(property:Gate)<-[:CanTravel]-(destination:Location) 
WHERE property.size IN ['medium', 'large'] AND location.name = 'Ellis' 
WITH location as start, destination, min(size([node in nodes(path) where node:Gate])) as travels
WITH start, collect({name:destination.name, travels:travels}) as locations
WITH locations + {name:start.name, travels:0} as locations
RETURN locations
```

EDIT 2

Regarding your jumppoint query, the reason you're getting that result is because you aren't filtering all :JumpPoints in the path, you're only filtering on the last :JumpPoint before your destination. If you want to filter all :JumpPoints, you'll need to do that explicitly, with something like:

```
WHERE all(jump in [node in nodes(path) where node:JumpPoint] WHERE jump.size in ['small']) and ...
```

Comment: Ok, so far so good. Thanks in advance! Now I want to that "Ellis" is also in the result, where "count" of course equal to 0, so that I can do more things with the result.

Finally:
Is it possible to pick the shortest Path to the destinations, because in the following picture you can see, which  Rels are following. I realize that this results in several paths, which is why I want to take the shortest.

https://www.instpic.de/R3H3KginlA3ZeJxUC4Ak.PNG

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Ok, I think the initial question is answered. I have added something that will help you to work with the result. Can find in my questen...
Thanks a lot!! That was really helpful for me!

Comment: Another question in the following post.

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: Updated with an answer. If you have any other followup questions those should probably be in different questions rather than appended to this one.

Comment: OMG! That was incredibly helpful to me! Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, I will do that. Wow! finally I will get on. Thanks again! Last but not least, the query is also very fast: 240 total db hits in 2 ms !!